# React to git update

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create a language server with the language server protocol. I'm currently testing it on visual studio code.
I can react to changes in the code by listening to the `textdocument/didChange` update.
However, if I do a `git pull` in the directory I don't receive any notification of all the modified files, except the actually opened file.
I'm confused because I thought that the whole workspace is watched by visual studio. Should I listen to another event for this kind of change?